# Share source between VisualStudio.com TFS & Codeplex TFS

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, azure-devops, codeplex

I am wanting to use VisualStudio.com to link work-items and user stories to source control check-ins for a current project of mine that is hosted on Codeplex.

The project is an open source project and has been hosted on Codeplex for several years. Now that I am doing a re-write, I am wanting to use an Agile process, creating user stories and building it in sprints, while I develop the app. The issue is that Codeplex's hosted TFS does not support this, while Visual Studio online does.

Visual Studio online is geared more towards closed-source projects with team members. It's offered for free, so I'm a bit bummed that they didn't open it up to support Open Source projects. Is there a way for me to have Visual Studio online host my source, and when I am ready to distribute a build, merge my branch in to Codeplex? I assume something along these lines is possible as the Prism team seems to do this with their releases. Since I don't have control over either TFS though, I'm not sure if external parties can do this or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use git on both projects (you can ask the Codeplex team to convert your project for you) then you can simply set up your git repo with two remotes.

Do you work locally and push to the main VSO git repo whenever you wish. When you've made enough changes that you want to push to Codeplex, just do a separate push to that remote and it'll be good to go.

If you're using TFVC on both then you're out of luck, unless you want to mess with the TFS Integration Platform (which I wouldn't recommend)

Comment: Thanks, I will shoot them an email and ask for them to convert it to a Git project and see how that goes.

Comment: Alright, this works friggen awesome! Thanks for the tip. Got my Codeplex project converted to Git, cloned it to VSO, and pushed changes to both Codeplex and VSO at the same time now. Much much better.